# CSS3 trying to get rid of some white space

Tags: css

```
    .abovearea
    {
      height: 100px;

      background: #f1f1f1;
      width:100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      overflow: hidden;

    }

      </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="abovearea">

Big Puppy

</div>
```

When I run the page on a browser I still see a bit of a white space on the sides and upper edge of the grey rectangle that contains the phrase "Big puppy".  How can I code my CSS so there are no blank spaces? and fills the whole viewing area instead?

thanks Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

To your `<style>` section, add `body { margin: 0 }`.